# regular expression for special chars and numerics

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression for accepting alpha numerics and special charecters also

like : abc & def12

thanks in advance
Nagesh

Comment: Please give some examples of waht you do and DO NOT want the regex to match.

Comment: In my opinion, `&` is not special at all.

Answer (score 2):

This might be the syntax you are looking for `/^[a-zA-Z0-9&:\/ ]+$/`, insert any other characters you want to match between the square brackets.

I would recommend you to read up on regular expressions if you intend to use them in the future, check out this tutorial http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Answer (score 1):

`^[\w]+$` this regex will match all alphanumerics, if you want to match some other chars as well just specify them in the `[]` brackets, i.e. if you wan't to also match ampersand you will have `^[\w&]+$` regex, if you wan't to match white characters as well (tabs, spaces, line feeds, carriage returns) you add `\d` and end up with `^[\w&\s]+$` and so on until you have all your special characters handled.

Comment: `^[\w&\s]$` matches a string consisting of only one character. Also note that `\w` not only matches alphanumerics, but in many regex flavors, it also matches an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

not got a specific answer, but [regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com/) has come in handy for me.